# How to correctly name field `body` in D?

Tags: class, naming-conventions, d

I would like to have a class field named `body` in my D application.

Like this:

```
class Posting
{
    // ...
    string heading, body, timestamp;
}
```

But when I try to compile this code, I get an error:

```
source/app.d(8): Error: no identifier for declarator string
source/app.d(8): Error: Declaration expected, not 'body'
```

Some googling around showed that `body` is a Dlang' keyword. But replacing it with some another name will cause many workaround code (I am trying to parse JSON with `yajl-d`).

So, the question is: how can I have the field named `body` in my class?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is one of the most annoying keywords in D because it could so easily be something else and body is a pretty common variable name.

But alas the answer is that you can't have a field named body in your class. You can try `Body` or `body_` or some variation of that, but `body` is no more doable than a variable named `class`.

The best solution would probably be to modify `yajl-d` to use an override name from a user defined attribute, if present, instead of the variable name when encoding or decoding. That'd be a fairly minor modification to the code, the function `getFieldName` from https://github.com/repeatedly/yajl-d/blob/master/src/yajl/common.d should do it.

edit: I went ahead and wrote the code on this fork: https://github.com/adamdruppe/yajl-d The readme shows an example now. See the code diff here: https://github.com/repeatedly/yajl-d/pull/6

Comment: And the PR just got merged upstream!